# How to create setup file in visual studio 2010 with .log file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-setup-proje, visual-studio-setup

I want to create setup file for my project with all prerequisites like framework,sqlserver and .log file/db script.

I want to run DB script during the installation of my setup. On single click i want to install all this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project solution Right click 
Add-> New Project-> Other Project Types-> Setup and Deployment Project -> Visual Studio  Installer -> Setup project.

Then Name your setup Project. Right click on setup  project Add-> primary Output and select your project displayed.

Again Right Click the setup project and select View-> File System -> Application Folder. Now copy what you want to be in installation folder.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353) is the example tutorial for creation of setup file.

To run your DBscript  on installation you should assign Custom Actions. View-> Custom Actions.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the step by step tutorial for  opening the web page after installation. In the same way you can assign your own custom action during installation, Roll back, commit and uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example tutorial for creation of setup file: http://dataerror.blogspot.com.br/2010/06/creating-web-setup-project-for-aspnet.html